# Use data from axios get as prop for another Vue file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have some code which resolves the ip address of a computer to a lat / long, like so

ip_resolve.vue

```
<script>
const axios = require('axios').default;
const ipRegex = /ip=(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})$/gmi
export default {
  name: 'ip',
  props: {
    ip: String,
    lat: String,
    long: String
  },
  mounted () {
    axios.get('https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace')
    .then(response => (
        this.ip = ipRegex.exec(response.data)[1]
    )
    .then(
        axios.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.ipstack.com/'+this.ip+'?access_key=<key>')
        .then( response => (
            this.lat = response.data.latitude,
            this.long = response.data.longitude
            )
        )
    )
    )
  }
}
</script>
```

I want to "return" the lat / long to App.Vue, where it will pass Lat/Long as props to "Weather.js"

App.Vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <ip></ip>
    <Weather lat={{lat}} long={{long}} />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Weather from './components/Weather.vue'
import ip from './components/ip_resolve.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Weather,
    ip
  }
}
</script>
```

I've read a little bit about $emit, but I am unfamiliar with the design paradigm and don't know how to implement it.  Can someone offer me some best practices here?

Thanks,

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't do the mounted/axios in App.vue itself? It would simplify things. You can pass the values by props to both ip and weather components if you need them in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ip_resolve.vue` use this to emit the event after getting the data from axios:

```js
this.$emit('response', {
  lat: response.data.latitude,
  long: response.data.longitude
}
```

And then in your `App.vue`:

```html
<ip @response="onResponse"></ip>
<Weather :lat="lat" :long="long" />
```

and inside `<script>` in `App.vue`:

```js
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      lat: 0,
      long: 0
    }
  },
  components: {
    Weather,
    ip
  },
  methods: {
    onResponse($event) {
      this.lat = $event.lat
      this.long = $event.long
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there.

This is how you can emit the data on your ip component:

```
<script>
const axios = require('axios').default;
const ipRegex = /ip=(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})$/gmi
export default {
  name: 'ip',
  props : {
    ip: String
  },
  mounted () {
    axios.get('https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace')
    .then(function(response) {
       this.ip = ipRegex.exec(response.data)[1]
       return axios.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.ipstack.com/'+this.ip+'?access_key=<key>')
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        this.$emit('change', {
           lat : response.data.latitude,
           long : response.data.longitude
          })
        })
  }
}
</script>
```

And then how you receive and push it to your weather component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <ip @update="updateCoords"></ip>
    <weather :lat="lat" :long="long" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Weather from './components/Weather.vue'
import ip from './components/ip_resolve.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Weather,
    ip
  },
  data : () => ({
    lat : null,
    long : null,
  }),
  methods : {
    updateCoords (coords) {
      this.lat = coords.lat
      this.long = coords.long
    }
}
}
</script>
```